# Using two models in one form in django 1.5

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

How can I use two models with OneToOne relation in one form using the CreateView in Django 1.5?

My models are these:

```
class Act(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class DetailAct(models.Model):
    detail = models.CharField()
    act = models.OneToOneField(Act)
```

My forms

```
class ActForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())

    class Meta:
        model = models.Act

class DetailActForm(forms.ModelForm):
    detail = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())

    class Meta:
        model = models.DetailAct
```

Thank you

Comment: But can I use the CreateView? I saw those examples but they're not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `Form` objects in one `<form>` tag without problems. Just make sure that you pass `prefix="form-1"` to one of the forms (or both - as long as the prefixes are different) in your view. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/226568/236195) for an example.

Nope, you can't use built-in class based views for this. Or, at least, not on the high-level you'd expect. You can make your own view class or mixin that will work with two forms, but AFAIK Django doesn't provide one.

Comment: Thank you, I am working with Symfony2 framework too and I thought django can achieve the same as symfony when you work with foreign keys in forms.