# Maintaining multiple instance of the same object in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating a small app in Django where I need to maintain details of training batches of different courses. Each of these batches will have a list of topics to be covered. For e.g, A python course could be conducted by different trainers in different colleges at the same time and so they both will have their own list of topics. Following  is what I have come up with but think I am wrong. I am confused about how to go about it. Kindly suggest the right approaches.

My Models so far,

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Course Name")

class Trainer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Trainer Name")

class College(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter College Name")

class CourseBatch(models.Model):
    startDate = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    endDate = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    batchName = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Batch Name")
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="course")
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(Trainer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="trainer")
    college = models.ForeignKey(College, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="college")

class CheckPoints(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Description")
    chkPoint = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="course")

class ChkListForBatch(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(CourseBatch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="coursebatch")
    chkpoint = models.ForeignKey(CheckPoints, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="chkpoint")
```

Here every CourseBatch needs to have its own set of CheckPoints (topics) to be covered. How can I implement the same?

Comment: Why you do not have ForeignKey relationship between CourseBatch and CheckPoints ?

Comment: I am confused about that as I want to have multiple Checkpoints to be associated with a single coursebatch. Also they should be saved as different objects. If I have a foreign key relationship I may be able to associate a single checkpoint but not multiple. That's why I created the ChkListForBatch. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I add answer, I add two field in CheckPoints model with comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand it, you have a list of checkpoints to each cource. And you want to choose, which checkpoints will be for each particular batch.

Updated. If you want to save the completed control point or not, do this:

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Course Name")

class Trainer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Trainer Name")

class College(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter College Name")

class CourseBatch(models.Model):
    startDate = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    endDate = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    batchName = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Batch Name")
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="course")
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(Trainer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="trainer")
    college = models.ForeignKey(College, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="college")

class CheckPoints(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Description")
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="course")

class ChkListForBatch(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(CourseBatch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="coursebatch")
    checkpoint = models.ForeignKey(CheckPoints, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="chkpoint")
    checkpoint_is_done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: This looks good to me, will try it out and then accept it as an answer. Also please let me know how would I populate these fields on a form when the data is coming from different models and is to be saved into different models, as I am new to Django

Comment: View at it first this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25674855/using-two-models-in-one-form-in-django-1-5. And note that the field names of the models need to be written in lower case letters https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/

Comment: Hi Vyacheslav, Thanks for your suggestions, however the link shows how to show the same form twice on the same web page. My issue is I wont have a model for form as I will be querying the data at run time (the ChkListForBatch items) for a given batch. So while creating a batch I'll have to query the checkpoints based on the course, then save them into ChkListForBatch and then show them on the form when the corresponding CourseBatch is selected

Comment: Your question is too broad and I do not quite understand what it is. I think you should start and then ask a question with a demonstration of your code.

Comment: Hi based on the original question, please suggest how can i populate the chkListForbatch automatically when a new CourseBatch is created (based on the selected course id and its checkpoints) from the admin interface. I don't want the user to manually populate the corresponding chkListForbatch items as that's repetitive mechanical work.

Comment: I think overriding the save_model method will do it!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Course Name")

class Trainer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Trainer Name")

class College(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter College Name")

class CourseBatch(models.Model):
    startDate = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    endDate = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    batchName = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Batch Name")
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="course")
    trainer = models.ForeignKey(Trainer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="trainer")
    college = models.ForeignKey(College, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="college")

class CheckPoints(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="Enter Description")
    chkPoint = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="course")
    course_batch = models.ForeignKey(to=CourseBatch, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # This means that you have multiple checkpoints associated with single coursebatch.
    course_batch_m2m = models.ManyToManyField(to=CourseBatch) # This will create intermediate model, with columns checkpoints_id | coursebatch_id. This means multiple checkpoints has multiple coursebatch and vice-versa.

class ChkListForBatch(models.Model):
    batch = models.ForeignKey(CourseBatch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="coursebatch")
    chkpoint = models.ForeignKey(CheckPoints, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="chkpoint")
```

Check CheckPoints model, I added `ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField` with explanaitans.